# Is organizing config files within a config group in a directory structure a supported feature in hydra?

Tags: fb-hydra

Let's assume a config group `foo` and config files organized in the following directory structure:

```
conf
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── a.yaml
│   │   ├── b.yaml
│   │   ├── c.yaml
│   └── baz
│       ├── d.yaml
│       ├── e.yaml
│       └── f.yaml
```

Each of the yaml files sets the package to `foo` using `# @package foo`. When running the corresponding application, I can simply override `foo` by specifying something like `foo=bar/a` or `foo=baz/f`. Thereby, the sub-directories `bar` and `baz` indicate a certain category withing a larger set of possible configurations.

While this works fine for standard use in hydra, some more advanced features of hydra appear to be not compatible with this structure. For instance, I would like to use glob in conjunction with the directory structure like this `foo=glob(bar/*)` to sweep over all configs of a certain category. However, this does not appear to work as glob does not find any configs in this example. Also if I assign an invalid config to `foo` and hydra lists the available options, the list is empty.

This makes me wonder if structuring within a config group is a generally supported feature in hydra, and just some corner cases are not covered yet, or if I am using hydra wrong and directories should not be used for organizing configs in a group?

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended, but not explicitly prohibited.
There are scenarios where this can help, but as you have discovered it does not play well with some other features. A config group contains other config groups/configs.

Hydra 1.1 is adding support for recursive default lists which will make this kind of scenario more common.
See [The Defaults List](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/defaults_list) documentation page:

```
├── server
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── mysql.yaml
│   │   └── sqlite.yaml
│   └── apache.yaml
└── config.yaml
```

In the scenario from the example there, the entities under server/db are different than the entities under server, so such globing would not make sense.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think that recursive default lists will help in my use-case. I will fall back to a naming scheme like `bar_a.yaml` so that I can do `glob(bar_*)` instead of `glob(bar/*)`. This isn't quite as neat as a directory hierarchy for a large number of configurations, but it should do the trick for now. I might open a feature request with a more concrete use-case and suggestion in the future.

Comment: See if you can leverage defaults list interpolation to simplify things.